# Making a list of variables without copying them

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

***The Main question:***
How do you create a pointer to a variable that can be stored and then used to access this variable at a later time *Without a copy being created*

---

***The below is here just to answer any questions that people might have as to why I want to do this***

**Prologue:**
I am making a game with DirectX and I want to create a  "list" of Entities(A special class) in a another class. I want to do this so I can keep track of all the objects in the game that are rendered by a specific method(One list for triangles, another for lines, ect). To do this I originally just had a class and it had a `std::vector<Entity>`, the class then had an `add(Entity entity)` function which would add the specified entity to the vector. This worked out very well until I started trying to make changes to these entities in the vector.

**The problem:**
First I would create an entity in the main world loop, `Entity testEntity = Entity(position);` then I would add it to the entity list, `entityList.add(testEntity);`. When this command is called it is actually just making a copy of the entity as it is at the time that the add command was called. This means that there are suddenly 2 entities that represent 1, The entity in the main world that is being affected by all the game logic, and the entity in the entityList that does not update, *but* renders.  These two are not in sync.

**The desired effect:**
The entityList's `std::vector` is actually just filled with some sort of pointer to the entities in the world loop. Then when an entity is updated in the world loop the entityList has the same data for that entity.

Comment: "How do you create a pointer to a variable that can be stored and then used to access this variable at a later time Without a copy being created" - with the `&` operator? I haven't read the rest of the question yet, but so far, I'm not sure what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not entirely clear to me where you're having trouble, so this may not answer the question:

It seems like you want to just store a vector of pointers to Entity objects.  I.e. `std::vector<Entity*>`.

If you know that testEntity will be in scope for the lifetime of the vector, you could just add a pointer to it to your vector.  I.e. `entityList.add(&testEntity)`.

If that assumption isn't true, you probably want to allocate your Entity objects on the heap (e.g. `Entity* testEntityPtr = new Entity(position);`.  If you're using C++11 (or maybe even if you're not), you probably want to use shared_ptr and make_shared in this situation.

Comment: I do not know if this works but in the process of implementing it like this I have run into an error when I try and use these entities in the entityList class functions. EX: `RenderController->entities->at(i)->getVertices();` where `RenderController` is the class that `entityList` is. It throws an error saying that `RenderController is illegal use of this type of expressions` and for every thing called(`at()`, `getVertices()`, and `entities`) on that line it says `must point to a class/stuct/union/generic type`

Comment: Continued... But when I init a temporary entity `Entity * tempEntity = RenderController::entities.at(i);` and then use `tempEntity` in the place of `RenderController->entities->at(i)` it works. Can you explain why this is?

Comment: Not sure, but if you've literally pasted your code, your non-working version says RenderController->, and your working version says RenderController::.  You probably want RenderController:: in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly use the c++ 11 Move Semantics to preserve your data. If `Entity` have pointer members that point to some allocated data that you do not want to copy you could implement Move semantics that would essentially transfer ownership the the copy that you are placing in the vector.
For example:

```
Entity(Entity&& entity)//move constructor
{
    this->data = std::move(entity.data);
    //and so on.
}
```

You will also need a "Move assignment operator" `Entity& operator=(Entity&& entity);`

You will need to look up "Move Semantics" and "rvalue references" for more info.

I hope this helps.